# My website is found on another domain which is not mine

Tags: redirect, dns, duplicates

Very strange problem. I have a website which is seo-techniques.net but suddenly I found another domain name- www.seiuc.com redirect my website. I am not sure how it is possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about domain names being redirected to specific sites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

www.seiuc.com is a [phising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) site, the webmaster of that website is trying to pretend as your official website. www.seiuc.com just copy pasted the content of your website. Report the offending webmaster to it's hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Question is how is your original domain redirects to the other one ? if that's the case it means that the other owner somehow injected a Redirect into one or all of your files or maybe changed your htaccess file - you should contact your hosting provider chat support asap - they'll will know how to fix it...